# Should 'require' go inside or outside of the Future?

Tags: scala, future

How do I replace my first conditional with the `require` function in the context of a Future? Should I wrap the entire **inRange** method in a Future, and if I do that, how do I handle the last Future so that it doesn't return a Future[Future[List[UserId]], or is there a better way?

I have a block of code that looks something like this:

```
class RetrieveHomeownersDefault(depA: DependencyA, depB: DependencyB) extends RetrieveHomeowners {
    def inRange(range: GpsRange): Future[List[UserId]] = {
        // I would like to replace this conditional with `require(count >= 0, "The offset…`
        if (count < 0) {
            Future.failed(new IllegalArgumentException("The offset must be a positive integer.")
        } else {
            val retrieveUsers: Future[List[UserId]] = depA.inRange(range)

            for (
                userIds <- retrieveUsers
                homes <- depB.homesForUsers(userIds)
            ) yield FilterUsers.withoutHomes(userIds, homes)
        }
    }
}
```

I started using the `require` function in other areas of my code, but when I tried to use it in the context of Futures I ran into some hiccups.

```
class RetrieveHomeownersDefault(depA: DependencyA, depB: DependencyB) extends RetrieveHomeowners {
    // Wrapped the entire method with Future, but is that the correct approach?
    def inRange(range: GpsRange): Future[List[UserId]] = Future {
        require(count >= 0, "The offset must be a positive integer.")

        val retrieveUsers: Future[List[UserId]] = depA.inRange(range)

        // Now I get Future[Future[List[UserId]]] error in the compiler.
        for (
            userIds <- retrieveUsers
            homes <- depB.homesForUsers(userIds)
        ) yield FilterUsers.withoutHomes(userIds, homes)
    }
}
```

Any tips, feedback, or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. I'm just getting started with Futures and still having a tough time wrapping my head around many concepts.

Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the outer `Future {...}` wrapper. It's not necessary. There's no good reason for the `require` call to go inside the `Future`. It's actually better outside since then it will report immediately (in the same thread) to the caller that the argument is invalid.

By the way, the original code is wrong too. The `Future.failed(...)` is created but not returned. So essentially it didn't do anything.

Comment: Good catch on the original `Future.failed(…)`, I corrected it.